# getter method for property crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access, getter-setter

I've declared a property someProperty and synthesized it:

@synthesize someProperty = _someProperty;

But when I call it in code, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS in my getter overide method. Why??

```
- (NSString *) someProperty {  <---EXC_BAD_ACCESS HERE
    if(!self.someProperty)
        return self.someOtherProperty;
    return self.someProperty;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you might be getting a **Stack Overflow!** because the line

```
if(!self.someProperty)
```

will be calling

```
- (NSString *) someProperty
```

recursively until the recursion stack overflows.

Similarly if it could get to the return line, it would do the same thing.

Comment: @user1337645: workaround could be using ivar `_someProperty` to hold value of property `someProperty` and then in getter you would be checking for `_someProperty` instead of `self.someProperty`. Also please don't forget to accept James's answer since it helped you find the problem.

Comment: Stack Overflow FTW! Seriously, if you run that code your app will crash after a few seconds and your call stack (left pane in Xcode, where the Project Navigator is usually) will quickly get full of entries pointing to this one accessor.